# pthread_setname_np() when capabilities are set

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, privileges, linux-capabilities

I compiled the example program from man [pthread_setname_np](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) with

```
g++ -pthread  example.cpp
```

And I set the cap_net_raw capability of my program a.out.

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw=+eip' a.out
```

Surprisingly the program fails when executing:

```
$./a.out
Created a thread. Default name is: a.out
pthread_setname_np: Permission denied
```

when I remove the capabilities it works..

```
$sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw=-eip' a.out
$./a.out
Created a thread. Default name is: a.out
The thread name after setting it is THREADFOO.
Done
```

So for me it looks like I have less privileges when I add a capability. Can anybody explain this?

Thanky you for your response ;-)

Some additional info:

- Capabilities are supported on my target I checked it with the ping command and CAP_NET_RAW
- Kernel 4.4.32-rt43
- RFS: ext4
- I reduced the post to the example program I agree it makes no sense to add the CAP_NET_RAW to this program.
- It would work if I add the CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a file system capability is in many ways just like making the program SUID/SGID.  In this `AT_SECURE == 1` execution mode, the kernel restricts what the original user can do with the process.  Potentially invasive actions, such as using `ptrace` to attach the the process or access to the process via `/proc`, are blocked by the kernel so that the user cannot use the program to escalate their privileges.  (glibc and other libraries disable some functionality for security reasons, too.)  Normally, these restrictions only apply to processes owned by *different* user IDs, but with capabilities (and SELinux contexts), a mere user ID comparison is no longer necessary to detect the crossing of a trust boundary.

In glibc, `pthread_setname_np` for a thread distinct from the current thread is implemented by writing to the `/proc/self/task/TID/comm` file, so it runs into these restrictions.  The kernel could conceivable implement an exception for this kind of self-modification of a task which shares the same address space, but it seems that this is not implemented, hence the failure.  And I can't really blame the kernel people because it's difficult to get such matters correct, not introducing any vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you Florian for the answer.
I also assume that pthread_setname_np tries to write to /proc/PID/comm if it is not the thread where the program is running.
What do you recommend me for a solution. Is it easy to write directly to  /proc/self/task/TID/comm..? So kind of write my own pthread_setname function.

Comment: So in my final solution I give the thread name as parameter to the function invoked in pthread_create and call in this function pthread_setname_np to set the name. Because setting the name is only allowed in the own thread as described by Florian.